# DDMS doesn't like ADB?

Tags: android, adb, ddms

I'm running into problems where a`db.exe` is working great on its own.

I'm able to communicate with my phone (HTC EVO) from a command line, but whenever I fire up eclipse (or even launch DDMS from `ddms.bat`), it won't maintain a connection with ADB.

Stuff I've tried:

1. I've tried '`kill-server/start-server`' to no avail.
2. Disabled VirusProtection / Firewalls
3. Using different drivers from `HTC`, `GoogleUSB`, and the generic `WindowsUSB`

My Setup: Eclipse 3.5.2, SDK Tools Rev. 9,  ADT 9.0.0., fresh WindowsXP,SP3 install.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I am having the same problem with another HTC device. Did you ever get it to work?